# gwtbootstrap3 tooltip wrap around multiple elements?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, gwt, tooltip, gwtbootstrap3

I am using gwtbootstrap3 Version: 0.9.4 in a gwt project.
I want to use the bootstraps tooltip for the navigation bar symbols.

```
<ui:UiBinder xmlns:ui="urn:ui:com.google.gwt.uibinder"
xmlns:g="urn:import:com.google.gwt.user.client.ui"
xmlns:b="urn:import:org.gwtbootstrap3.client.ui">...
```

If I wrap the Tooltip around an Anchor in an ui.xml file of its corresponding Java Class, it works fine:

```
<b:Tooltip ui:field="someName" text="TEST">
    <g:Anchor ui:field="someOtherName">someText</g:Anchor>
</b:Tooltip>
```

But now comes the problem:
If I want to wrap an Anchor which contains another element like a span, the Tooltips text is not displayed anymore (by hover) when running the project. In fact, no tooltip appears at all for this icon. But the project still compiles and runs.

```
<b:Tooltip text="TEST">
    <g:Anchor ui:field="someName">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-someglyph white" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="white">someText</span>
    </g:Anchor>
</b:Tooltip>
```

I read the documentation from the Tooltip class:
https://gwtbootstrap3.github.io/gwtbootstrap3-demo/apidocs/org/gwtbootstrap3/client/ui/Tooltip.html

but as far as I saw it is not explicitly said that Tooltip allows only one element inside, so does anyone now how to solve this?

Thanks!

Comment: Your code works for me... i can see the Tooltip.

Comment: thanks for the answer. that's strange because for me it didn't work, but I figured another way to solve this by using the internal NavbarButton from gwtbootstrap3 which can easily be wrapped by a Tooltip widget!
With the NavbarButton you don't need the spans inside because it has integrated enum Icons (glyphs) which can chosen